# jedi-vim doesn't find python2 dist-packages, but python3 yes

Tags: python, ubuntu, vim, jedi, jedi-vim

Jedi-vim does autocompletion for python3 dist-packages, but can't fnd python 2.7 dist-packages. I run my program using python 2 without problem. Everything else runs correctly. I found out that vim is running with python3.

I'm using **Ubuntu 16.04** that comes with both python2.7 and python3 installed, but uses python2.7 by default. I've installed jedi with pip for python2, and jedi-vim with Bundle.

Is there a way to set the path of jedi-vim to look for python2 dist-packages? Do I need to compile vim using python 2 instead?

I added this line in my .vimrc file trying to change the version:

```
let g:jedi#force_py_version = 2
```

And I got this error message.

```
Error: jedi-vim failed to initialize Python: Could not setup g:jedi#force_py_ver
sion: jedi#setup_py_version: Vim(pyfile):E319: Sorry, the command is not availab
le in this version: pyfile /home/santi/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim/initialize.py (in fu
nction jedi#init_python[3]..<SNR>65_init_python, line 6)
```

Works fine when settings the version to 3 though.

**vim --version:**

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jun 16 2016 10:50:38)
(...)
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -Wdate-time  -g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux  -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl     -L/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.5m -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm
```

**python (2.7): print sys.path**

```
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/santi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0']
```

**python3 print(sys.path)**

```
['', '/usr/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

**.vimrc**

```
Plugin 'davidhalter/jedi-vim'
```

Comment: You can switch the Python interpreter. Read the jedi-vim's README.

Comment: @DaveHalter: I have the same problem with my Ubuntu 16.10 installation.  The same error message when I have the line `let g:jedi#force_py_version = 2` in my .vimrc, and the same error when I do `:call jedi#force_py_version(2)`.  If I replace 2 with 3 in those commands though there is no error.

Comment: Maybe add an issue to the jedi-vim tracker? I have not implemented that part and I feel like this is either a bug or your installation is wrong (and therefore I think stackoverflow is probably not the right place to figure this out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

The problem was that I had the vim installed with python3 support and not python2. I think is default for Ubuntu 16.04. You can checked with:

```
vim --version | grep python
```

If you output looks like this:

```
+cryptv          +linebreak       -python          +vreplace
+cscope          +lispindent      +python3         +wildignore
```

Then you can run these commands to solve the problem:

```
sudo apt install vim-gnome-py2
sudo update-alternatives --set vim /usr/bin/vim.gnome-py2
sudo update-alternatives --set gvim /usr/bin/vim.gnome-py2
```

Check again for the plus in the python

```
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +vreplace
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +wildignore
```

That's it. Worked for me

Thanks to https://github.com/JBakamovic/yavide/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md